# How to check with javascript if call is made to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am calling google api (fetching thousands of record in json), saving records in database and then showing all records on next page.
I want to show loading gif until next page load. I have used jquery (see code below) but it is not working as desired because the loading image shows up only when next page starts loading and that div gets fade out when that next page finishes loading.
It is not shown up when call is made to google api.

```
<script>
    // Wait for window load
            $(window).load(function() {
                // Animate loader off screen
                $("#bg").fadeOut("slow");
                $("#imgLoading").fadeOut("slow");;
            });
</script>
```

How can i check with JavaScript if call is made to server so i can show that loading gif. I don't want to call that function on button click, i want it to be generic so when ever there is call made to server show loading image and finishes showing up when next page finishes loading.

Thanking you in advance !!

Comment: In a comment below you say you don't want to use AJAX. What do you mean by "a call to the server" then? Loading an entirely new page?

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Comment: Yes, calling entirely new page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround:
Well i got one workaround, i started displaying loading image `onSubmit` event of the form. And on next page started displaying same loading image until page loads completely. 
So loading image started when button is pressed until next page loads completely.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Jquery then I suggest to take a look at [this](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)

It is as easy as possible.

```
$( document ).ajaxSend(function() {
  $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxSend handler." );
});
```

Comment: I don't want to use ajax.

Comment: @Anjum than your question is misleading. What you actually want is to *know when a page finishes loading*?

Comment: My question is not misleading, I have clearly mentioned that i want to show loading image when call is made. I am already showing on page load.

Comment: @Anjum Your question **is** misleading because by "a call" you mean something different than the rest of the world does. So what does "a call" mean, if not an AJAX call and not a page load?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps:

**Add the below div right below the opening  tag.**

```
<div class="loader"></div>
```

**Add some CSS**

```
.loader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url('images/page-loader.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
}
```

**Add jQuery and a line of code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
})
</script>
```

**Note:** Please make sure that jquery.min.js is included in your file

Comment: This is what i am already doing, I want to show that loading image when call is made to server

Comment: Are you using it for page load or ajax loading?

Comment: how are you making the request to google api server? I mean through javascript or other?

Comment: It is asp.net application, I am making call using call back. I am not using JavaScript to make call.